# Задача должна решиться двойным циклом, а не тройным

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, циклы

Программа ищет все пифагоровы тройки от 1 до n. Работает верно, но как переделать я просто не понимаю

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Piff3(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
    int n, a, b, c;
    cout << "Enter N\n";
    cin >> n;
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
        for (b = 1; b <= c; b++)
            for (a = 1; a <= b; a++) {
                if (Piff3(c, b, a) == 1)
                    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
            }
    return 0;
}

int Piff3(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (((z * z) + (y * y)) == (x * x))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что в данном случае n?

Comment: @Эникейщик максимальное значение гипотенузы в треугольнике

Comment: Так а зачем тут вообще третий цикл? Просто проверяйте, является ли `z*z + y*y` точным квадратом.

Comment: @Yaant это как? Можно подробнее???

Comment: Взять квадратный корень от z\*z + y\*y, и проверить, является ли он целым числом.

Comment: @AlexF но как приспособить это к моему коду? Я очень туплю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополнил ваш код с помощью функции из комментариев, чтобы избежать третьего цикла.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, a, b, c;
    cout << "Enter N\n";
    cin >> n;
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
        for (b = 1; b <= c; b++)
            if(is_perfect_square(c * c - b * b))
                 cout << (int)sqrt(c * c - b * b) << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool is_perfect_square(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return false;
    int root = round(sqrt(n));
    return n == root * root;
}
```

Comment: Если n - гипотенуза, то или с идет не до n, или не участвует определении точного квадрата.

Comment: Проверять булевые значение на ==true не надо.

Comment: Забавное у вас решение... сначала засунуть `n` в `sqrt`, а затем проверять, не меньше ли оно нуля? :) не хотите поменять строки местами?